# Uncaught TypeError: canvas.clear is not a function

Tags: fabricjs

I have a canvas set up with fabric.js 1.7.21 and I'm getting this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: canvas.clear is not a function
    at clearcan (myapp.js:25)
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (index.html:43)
```

From `myapp.js`:

```
function clearcan() {
  var txt;
  if (confirm("Chuck this?") == true) {
    canvas.clear().renderAll();
    newleft = 0;
  }
}
```

From my `index.html`:

```
<button onclick="clearcan();" type="button"></button>
```

I'm not sure what's going on. What am I missing?

[Here's a JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/code4ever/1qwt8knz/)

Comment: is canvas a `fabric.Canvas` instance?

Comment: Yes, I've got `var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');` set

Comment: can you make a snippet or fiddle?

Comment: @Durga [Here's a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/code4ever/1qwt8knz/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you were initializing the canvas instance inside a self invoking function so that canvas instance is not available inside your clearcan() function.

Remove that function , it will be on global scope, so you can access it in other functions. Here is updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1qwt8knz/2/)

```
var canvas = this.__canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
function clearcan() {
  var txt;
  if (confirm("Chuck this?")) {
    canvas.clear().renderAll();
    newleft = 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: You are the man! That seemed to do the trick. On this same vein, when I started adding objects, things seem to be appearing behind the canvas? What might be causing this, from what we just did? [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/code4ever/1qwt8knz/4/)

Comment: it will be on canvas, why behind?

Comment: That's what I thought, but it appears behind the background color?

Answer (score 0):

In HTML5 Canvas Tutorial -
 https://www.html5canvastutorials.com/advanced/html5-clear-canvas/ said that:

> To clear the HTML5 Canvas, we can use the clearRect() method to clear the canvas bitmap.

So please try with

> context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

Comment: OP asked to clear the canvas which uses fabricjs library.

Answer (score 0):

The best way for removing all the objects that are present on canvas using fabricJS is

```
 var objectsInGroup= this.canvas.getObjects().map(function(o) {
  return o.set('active', true);
});
canvas.discardActiveGroup();
objectsInGroup.forEach(function(object) {
canvas.remove(object);
});
```